# How the textViewResourceId assigned by android while using ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, android-adapter

I am new to Android so forgive me if this is an obvious one, i am still trying to understand the workflow.
I am following a tutorial and I have created a listView and an ArrayAdapter.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,names);
```

Then I got curious and take a look at the ArrayAdapter constructor. In the constructor the textViewResourceId is set to **0**.

```
public ArrayAdapter(@NonNull Context context, @LayoutRes int resource,
            @NonNull List<T> objects) {
     //Here textViewResourceId is set to 0     
     this(context, resource, 0, objects);
}
```

Then i looked at the source of **android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1**. At this point i expected the id of **@android:id/text1** would be **0**, but when i checked it the editor shows me `public static final int text1 = 16908308`

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
    android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall" />
```

I am getting something wrong here, anyone could breifly explain me what is going on here? 
Thanks.

Comment: If the text view ID is not specified, it assumes the layout resource specified is itself a `TextView`, as you can see [on this line](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java#L431). This is the case in the layout you shared, the root view is a `TextView`. So it doesn't need an ID.

Comment: @Nicolas Thanks a lot, i think i found it almost at the same time. If you would write a reply i can mark your it as the accepted answer, better than accepting mine :)

Comment: No thanks, I'm happy you could figure it out by yourself! The answers are often found in the android code, you just need to take a look.

Answer (score 0):

I have looked further to the source code and found out the reason. I would be happy if this helps anyone.

```
       if (mFieldId == 0) {
            //  If no custom field is assigned, assume the whole resource is a TextView
            text = (TextView) view;
       } else {
             //  Otherwise, find the TextView field within the layout
            text = view.findViewById(mFieldId);
```